# How to get Date in proper format in symfony2 writing own console Command

Tags: php, symfony

How to get Date in proper format in symfony2 writing own console Command

```
$plantype = $allDbName->getPlanType();
$planEndOn = $allDbName->getNextPaymentDate();
$p = $planEndOn->format('H:i:s \O\n Y-m-d');
$currentDate = new \DateTime();

$date =   date_modify($p, '-5 day');

$output->writeln($date);
```

getting error in console

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$date = date_modify(planEndOn, '-5 day'); $output->writeln($date->format('H:i:s \O\n Y-m-d'));` ?

Comment: yes i have tried see in screenshot i have edited not i got this error

Comment: Ok, have you see my update?

Comment: i had tried it It is not working
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution

$planEndOn = $allDbName->getNextPaymentDate() ? $allDbName->getNextPaymentDate()->format('Y-m-d') : 0;

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime::format()` returns a string, so `$p` is a string, not a DateTime.

You should do something like this instead

```
$planEndOn = $allDbName->getNextPaymentDate();
$planEndOn->modify('-5 days');
$output->writeln($planEndOn->format('H:i:s \O\n Y-m-d'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The errormessage is clear,

```
date_modify($p, '-5 day');
```

expects `$p` to be a dateTime Object

but at this point its a string because you already formatted as string with  `->format()`
so change the order of your script :

```
$plantype = $allDbName->getPlanType();
$planEndOn = $allDbName->getNextPaymentDate();
$p =   date_modify($planEndOn, '-5 day');
$date = $p->format('H:i:s \O\n Y-m-d');

$output->writeln($date);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for help but i m getting this error 
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: date_modify() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, null given